# combining two columns while factoring in r

Tags: r

I have a situation like below:

[image]

I want to factor based on the combination of PART-APPLICABILITY:
PART1-FORD as factor 1,                                                       PART1-infinity as factor 2,                                                  PArt1-MERC as factor 3, PART2-Infinty as factor 4 so on.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two columns using `paste`

```
factor( paste(PART, APPLICABILITY, sep="-") )
```